# Powershell ACL not being set

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm trying to set an ACL to only modify, but when I run the code it runs through, but the permissions are still blank for the specified user, where am i going wrong?

```
$ApplicationPoolIdentity = "domain\username"

function SetACL()
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]        $Path 
    )

    $Acl = Get-Acl $Path
    Write-Host "Path:" $Path "ID:" $ApplicationPoolIdentity
    $Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($ApplicationPoolIdentity,"Write","Allow")
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    Write-Host $Acl
    $Acl | Set-Acl $Path
}

SetACL "F:\Test123\"
```

Comment: This code is working on my system.

Comment: :( i guess it might be permissions or something.. doesn't return a error though